# default git behavior I don't understand

Tags: git, git-branch

I have not decided if I like the following behavior regarding files / folders that are not under version control.

In particular, it seems strange that un-versioned files seem to follow you when you checkout different branches. It seems like said files should only exist in the branch they were created in.

Can someone please help me understand why / if this is desirable behavior?

For example:

```
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ ls
hello.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git branch  
-
* master
my_branch
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ 
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git checkout my_branch 
Switched to branch 'my_branch'
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ mkdir adir
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ touch adir/my_branch.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git add adir/
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git commit -a -m "added adir with my_branch.txt"
[my_branch d36964c] added adir with my_branch.txt
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git checkout my_branch
Switched to branch 'my_branch'
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ tree
.
|-- adir
|   |-- my_branch.txt
|   `-- orphan.txt
`-- hello.txt

1 directory, 3 files

create mode 100644 adir/my_branch.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ touch adir/orphan.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ ls
adir  hello.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ tree
.
|-- adir
|   `-- orphan.txt
`-- hello.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

**EDIT** 
    As it turns out, nothing was changed in the files between the branches in the following first edit. Thanks for the help everyone!

**EDIT**
It seems that git does not write modification of versioned files when checkouts occur. In the following example, another.txt is not under version control:

```
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 shopkins shopkins 4096 2011-02-21 21:49 adir
-rw-r--r-- 1 shopkins shopkins    0 2011-02-21 21:47 another.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 shopkins shopkins    0 2011-02-21 21:49 hello.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ git checkout my_branch
Switched to branch 'my_branch'
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 shopkins shopkins 4096 2011-02-21 21:49 adir
-rw-r--r-- 1 shopkins shopkins    0 2011-02-21 21:47 another.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 shopkins shopkins    0 2011-02-21 21:49 hello.txt
shopkins@shax:~/tmp/test$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't even know that the un-versioned files exist. Technically they aren't even part of the repository. That is why they are called "un-versioned files." Git does not modify, delete, store, or keep track of any file unless it is told to.

The classic situation where this is desirable is if your software generates temporary files as part of its build process, or if the compiled executables are left in the same directory as the source code. Obviously, if someone is cloning your repository so they can download your software from you, you would want all those files to be "left behind." But more importantly, you would not want them cluttering up the version history. It doesn't matter when these files change, only when the source code changes. So seeing diffs of these files with every commit will only make it harder to find the information you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was worried about such temporary files (like compiled executables) causing problems if trying to re-compile between different branches. Say you switch to one branch and execute a make command, then switch to a different one and execute another make, will the compiler think everything is up to date because of the date-modified attrs of the files / executables?

Comment: I believe GIT writes the file modification time as the moment you do a branch switch (if an update to the file is required on the switch).  This mean make will see any dependencies on this file as not met and recompile them.  I can't speak for other build systems, but I believe they all work in a similar manner.

Comment: I tested what I think you mean. CAn you please take a look at the edit?

Comment: well nothing has actually changed between those two branches.  You are looking at the same node on the git tree. You would need to have different content in some.file.

Comment: If the versioned files need not be changed in order to switch between branches, they won't be. If the branches actually contained different versions of the files, your results would have been different.

Comment: Of course. Got a little carried away there :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

well this can make builds faster as un-added output hangs around between branch switches and you don't have your make output to some external directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why would git delete a file it can't restore?
Git just leaves alone the files it doesn't know about.

Comment: If I were to add the orphan.txt file to my_branch and commit the changes, then checkout back to master, 'adir' does no longer exist. I wonder why it will leave the directory in there until it has no un-versioned files?

Comment: Git will never delete files unless it is specifically told to. It will keep directories if they contain files it hasn't been told to delete.

Comment: @Max E. Yes. That was a rhetorical question. @Hersheezy My point is: git shouldn't delete untracked files, because it can't restore them.